# How to create a dynamic (on the fly) form in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I am working in a sencha touch ap and I need to generate views with dynamic forms.

Configuration comes from the backend (JSON) and depending of this I paint a component or other.. for example:

```
 "auxiliaryGroups": [
      {
        "id": "1000",
        "name": "Basic Data",
        "fields": [
          {
            "id": "1001",
            "name": "Company name",
            "editable": true,
            "mandatory": true,
            "calculation": true,
            "internalType": "T",
            "type": "textfield",
            "options": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
```

Where type is related xtype in Sencha.

In the view I am creating all options of fields:

```
      {
        xtype : 'fieldset',
        itemId: 'auxiliaryFieldsGroup3',
        title: 'Requirements',
        //cls   : 'headerField',
        items:[
          {
            xtype: 'togglefield',
            name: 'f6',
            label: 'Auxiliary field R1'
          },
          {
            xtype: 'selectfield',
            name: 'f10',
            label: 'Auxiliary field R5',
            placeHolder: 'Select one..',
            options: [
              {text: 'First Option',  value: 'first'},
              {text: 'Second Option', value: 'second'},
              {text: 'Third Option',  value: 'third'}
            ]
          },
          {
            xtype: 'textfield'
          }  
        ] 
      }
```

And I receive the configuration from the server, I understand the view like a store of different fields, and from the controller, it should add only fields specified in the json object.

How to create this dynamically following MVC concept?

Thank you

Comment: Is there any reason that you do not use ExtJS declarative syntax of defining a form? With this structure you need to write a custom render method that could be complicated. But with ExtJS syntax it would be much more easier.

Comment: Any example about your idea?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have all the fields in the `auxiliaryGroups.fields` array.
After loading the form data from AJAX you can do it like this in your success call.

```
  succses:function(response){
   var response = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
   var fields = response.auxiliaryGroups.fields;
   var form = Ext.create("Ext.form.Panel",{
                                   // here your form configuration.
                                    cls:"xyz"
                                  });
   Ext.Array.forEach(fields,function(field){
      var formField = {
          xtype: field.type,
          label: field.name,
          name: field.id
       };
       form.add(formField);
   });

   Ext.Viewport.add(form);
   form.show();
  }
```

Comment: thank your for your response, but it is not working..  :-(

Comment: Instead of a request, I am saving the data in a store.. any clue about the implementation ?  thank you..

Answer (score 1):

Based on my comment on your question, my idea about dynamic form generation is using ExtJS syntax to load form definition would be something like the code below; of course it would be extended and the data can be loaded from the server.

```
Ext.require([
  'Ext.form.*'
]);

Ext.onReady(function() {
  var data = [{
    fieldLabel: 'First Name',
    name: 'first',
    allowBlank: false
  }, {
    fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
    name: 'last'
  }, {
    fieldLabel: 'Company',
    name: 'company'
  }, {
    fieldLabel: 'Email',
    name: 'email',
    vtype: 'email'
  }, {
    xtype: 'timefield',
    fieldLabel: 'Time',
    name: 'time',
    minValue: '8:00am',
    maxValue: '6:00pm'
  }];

  var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    frame: true,
    title: 'Simple Form',
    bodyStyle: 'padding:5px 5px 0',
    width: 350,
    fieldDefaults: {
      msgTarget: 'side',
      labelWidth: 75
    },
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    defaults: {
      anchor: '100%'
    }
  });

  form.add(data);
  form.render(document.body);

});
```

**update:**

When you create a view in run-time, communication between view and controller might be problematic because the controller doesn't know anything about the view. considering that the controller is responsible for initializing the view with appropriate data and handling view's events, data binding mechanism in ExtJS can solve the first part (initializing the view) which is described at [View Models and Data Binding](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/application_architecture/view_models_data_binding.html), the second part (handling view's events) can be solved with general methods in the controller, every element in the view should send its event to some specific methods and the methods based on the parameters should decide what to do.

This approach makes your methods in the controller a little fat and complicated that is the price of having dynamic form.

It is worth to mention that EXTJS raises different events in the life cycle of controllers and views and you should take benefit of them to manage your dynamic form.

Comment: and could you please help me with an approach to "intelligent" form? At the moment I have added all different xtype to the view, but I would need to think manage the controller and hide or show depending of the parameter from the server... do you know what I mean? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want your generated form's elements be manipulated by the code in run-time? I mean something like applying user access control in some elements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Touch, but in ExtJS, I usually do it by using the `add` function of a `fieldset`. You just loop through all your records, and create the fields on the fly.

```
var field = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text'); //or Ext.form.field.Date or a number field, whatever your back end returns.
```

Then set correct config options on `field` then

```
formFieldset.add(field);
```

Comment: yes, testing with the add method works, but I need a complex and dynamic form and this structure you know clearly the field..  Thank you

Comment: @inane Then we need more information about what your backend returns and what you actually want.

Comment: if you see my last edit of the example, I am receiving this object and the "type" is the sencha component.. imagine 15 objects with different components painted sequentially in a vertical layout.. I need in a view, render the result of the json

Comment: @inane You need to know all the possible `types` the backend will return, then use a `switch` to translate to correct ExtJS class names

Comment: yes I have created a little method with a switch, but I have problems with the controller, and how to loop around the json and paint different fields... for other hand, I have to say I am working with a segmentedbutton, switching among views, and for each view I should to show a dynamic form.. do you know what I mean?  thanks for your help until now..

Comment: @inane Would be glad to help, but your problem seems to be something else than adding fields to a form on the fly. Maybe you need to re-edit your question and mention issues with the controller, add some code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96286/discussion-between-inane-and-francis-ducharme).